# Date time conversion error when converting varchar date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert this date time format `'01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM'` to
`'2019-02-01'` format.

I have written this code:

```
declare @start_date datetime;
declare @end_date datetime;

set @start_date = '01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM';
set @end_date = '28/02/2019 12:00:00 AM';

select * 
from test 
where [Global Dimension 1 Code] in ('FIN') 
  and convert(char(10), [Posting Date], 126) between convert(date, convert(char(10), @start_date, 126), 103)  
                                                 and convert(date, convert(char(10), @end_date, 126), 103)
```

But I'm getting an error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 8
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

but when I have run the query as below It was executed without an error.

```
select * 
from test 
where [Global Dimension 1 Code] in ('FIN') 
  and convert(char(10), [Posting Date], 126) between convert(date, convert(char(10), '01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 126), 103) 
                                                 and convert(date, convert(char(10), '28/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 126), 103)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 103

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 103)
```

or

```
SELECT convert(char(10), '01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 126)
```

Comment: yes it's working for the  SELECT convert(datetime, '01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 103) . Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

use below  with `cast()` and `format()` - will work sql server 2012+

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2943cf35b21ab44396f1a5c844dbec6b)**

```
select format(cast('01/02/2019 12:00:00 AM' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: getting an error  @fa06  'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: yes, format function is available in sql server 2012 version @Haz